# Graphql don't work in magento 2, please help me

Tags: magento2, graphql

I create a module in magento 2 to test Graphql, but it's not work.

## my schema.graphqls

```
#Coppy codilar Blog
type Query{
    codilarblog: Codilarblog @resolver(class : "Codilar\\GraphQlDemo\\Model\\Resolver\\Blog") @doc(description: " the query return something")
}

type Codilarblog @doc(description : "Codilarblog defines the blog name and "){
    entity_id: Int
    blog_name: String
    author: String
    blog_content : String
}
```

## my Resolver/Blog

```
<?php

namespace Codilar\GraphQlDemo\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\Value;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\ValueFactory;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

class Blog implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ValueFactory
     */
    private $valueFactory;

    /**
     * Blog constructor.
     * @param ValueFactory $valueFactory
     */
    public function __construct(ValueFactory $valueFactory)
    {
        $this->valueFactory = $valueFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param Field $field
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param ResolveInfo $info
     * @param array|null $value
     * @param array|null $args
     * @return Value|mixed
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
    {
        try {
            $blog = $this->getBlogArray();
            $result = function () use ($blog) {
                return !empty($blog) ? $blog : [];
            };
            return $this->valueFactory->create($result);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            throw new \Exception(__($exception->getMessage()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getBlogArray()
    {
        $blog = [
            'entity_id' => 1,
            'blog_name' => 'Some blog name',
            'author' => 'Some Author Name',
            'blog_content' => 'Hi, this is blog content.'
        ];
        return $blog;
    }
}
```

## my folder module

[image]

## error after i upgrade and run :

[image]

Comment: not working mean, Your query or resolver? Where is the error?

Comment: thanks, i will show it.

Comment: there might be an issue in your resolver. Add a logger file and check you can reach to resolver file first. if you can reach resolver file try to get the result to your logger. Your schema.graphqls and your query seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you please try this:**

```
type Query {
    codilarblog: Codilarblog @resolver(class : "Codilar\\GraphQlDemo\\Model\\Resolver\\Blog") @doc(description: " the query return something")
}

type Codilarblog {
    entity_id: Int
    blog_name: String
    author: String
    blog_content : String
}
```

**Run Below Commands**

```
 php bin/magento s:up 
 php bin/magento s:di:c 
 php bin/magento c:f
```

[image]